# C++ template parameter specify the second

Tags: c++, c++17

this is my code:

```cpp
template <typename T, int index>
int echo(T t) {
    return index - 1;
}
echo<3>(1); // error: invalid template argument for 'T', type expected
```

I think that the compiler is fully capable to deduce `T`.
How can I do to use `echo` when `T` is the first template parameter except below:

```
echo<decltype(x), 3>(x);
```

Comment: Swap the parameters over and put index first?

Comment: Swap `T` and `index` can solve, but I want to know the solution when `T` is the first.

Comment: you can't, only parameters after the explicitly specified ones can be deduced

Comment: It's similar like with default function arguments. You may leave them out in the call but only if all following are left out as well.

Comment: You still have the option to write a wrapper template which just swaps the template arguments: [**demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bceb02b158dbc08f)